# calculate distance; substract the first column of the second line from the second column of the fist line using awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a question. I have a file with coordinates (`TAB` separated)

```
2 10
35 50
90 200
400 10000
...
```

I would like to substract the first column of the second line from the second column of the fist line , i.e. calculate the distance, i.e. I would like a file with

```
25
40
200
...
```

How could I do that using awk???
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 6):

here is an awk one-liner may help you:

```
kent$  awk 'a{print $1-a}{a=$2}'  file
25
40
200
```

Comment: Woah Kent. You simplified my way of looking with awk. Thanks

Comment: Note that this will work only if the second column is never zero

Comment: Then `awk 'NR>1 && $0{print $1-a}{a=$2}' file` could make it, but I guess it is an edge case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution:

```
{
    read _ ps
    while read f s; do
        echo $((f-ps))
        ((ps=s))
    done
} < input_file
```

This only works if you have (small) integers, as it uses bash's arithmetic. If you want to deal with arbitrary sized integers or floats, you can use `bc` (with only one fork):

```
{
    read _ ps
    while read f s; do
        printf '%s-%s\n' "$f" "$ps"
        ps=$s
    done
} < input_file | bc
```

Now I leave the others give an awk answer!

---

Alright, since nobody wants to upvote my answer, here's a really funny solution that uses [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and `bc`:

```
a=( $(<input_file) )
printf -- '-(%s)+(%s);\n' "${a[@]:1:${#a[@]}-2}" | bc
```

or the same with `dc` (shorter but doesn't work with negative numbers):

```
a=( $(<input_file) )
printf '%s %sr-pc' "${a[@]:1:${#a[@]}-2}" | dc
```

Answer (score 1):

using sed and ksh for evaluation

```
sed -n "
1x
1!H
$ !b

x
s/^ *[0-9]\{1,\} \(.*\) [0-9]\{1,\} *\n* *$/\1 /
s/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\(\n\)\([0-9]\{1,\}\) /echo \$((\3 - \1))\2/g
s/\n *$//
w /tmp/Evaluate.me
"
. /tmp/Evaluate.me
rm /tmp/Evaluate.me
```